# Hash table of linked list

Tags: c

add()

dislay()

delete_value()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linked_list{
    int value;
    struct ll *next;
    struct node_struct *prev;
}ll;

#define asize 10
ll *hash[asize];


int add(int element, int value){
    ll *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
    ll *head = hash[element];

    temp->value = value;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (hash[element] == NULL){
        temp->prev = NULL;
        head = temp;
    }
    else {
        while (head->next != NULL){
            head = head->next;
        }
        head->next = temp;
        temp->prev = head;
        while (head->prev != NULL){
            head = head->prev;
        }
    }
    hash[element] = head;
}

void delete_value(int value){
    int bol = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < asize; i++){
        ll *head = hash[i];
        ll *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL){
            if (temp->value == value){
                bol = 1;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (bol == 1){
            if (temp == head){
                head = temp->next;
                hash[i] = head;
            }
            else {
                ll *prev = temp->prev;
                prev->next = temp->next;
                while (head->prev != NULL){
                    head = head->prev;
                }
                hash[i] = head;
            }
            free(temp);
            bol = 0;
        }
    }
}

void display(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < asize; i++){
        printf("%d) ", i);
        if (hash[i] == NULL){
            printf("NULL");
        }
        else if (hash[i]->next == NULL){
            printf("[ %d ]", hash[i]->value);
        }
        else {
            ll *head = hash[i];
            printf("[ ");
            while (head->next != NULL){
                printf("%d, ", head->value);
                head = head->next;
            }
            printf("%d ]", head->value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int choice = 0, value;
    int element;
    while (1){
        printf("\tAddend - 1\n\tDisplay - 2\n\tDelete - 3\n");
        printf(" > ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1){
            system("cls");
            printf("-->Enter item: ");
            scanf("%d", &element);
            printf("-->Enter value: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            add(element, value);
        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            system("cls");
            printf("-->Display");
            printf("\n");
            display();
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            system("cls");
            printf("-->Delete\n");
            printf("-->Enter value: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            delete_value(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот тут `if (hash == NULL){` я думаю, нужно `head` вместо `hash` (далее не читал...)

Comment: Не понял, что значит "заливать". Если вы имеете в виду, как поправить вопрос, то внизу под его текстом есть поле `править`. Нажимаете и редактируете текст вопроса

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linked_list{
    int value;
    struct ll *next;
    struct node_struct *prev;
}ll;

#define asize 10
ll *hash[asize];


int add(int element, int value){
    ll *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
    ll *head = hash[element];

    temp->value = value;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (hash[element] == NULL){
        temp->prev = NULL;
        head = temp;
    }
    else {
        while (head->next != NULL){
            head = head->next;
        }
        head->next = temp;
        temp->prev = head;
        while (head->prev != NULL){
            head = head->prev;
        }
    }
    hash[element] = head;
}

void delete_value(int value){
    int bol = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < asize; i++){
        ll *head = hash[i];
        ll *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL){
            if (temp->value == value){
                bol = 1;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (bol == 1){
            if (temp == head){
                head = temp->next;
                hash[i] = head;
            }
            else {
                ll *prev = temp->prev;
                prev->next = temp->next;
                while (head->prev != NULL){
                    head = head->prev;
                }
                hash[i] = head;
            }
            free(temp);
            bol = 0;
        }
    }
}

void display(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < asize; i++){
        printf("%d) ", i);
        if (hash[i] == NULL){
            printf("NULL");
        }
        else if (hash[i]->next == NULL){
            printf("[ %d ]", hash[i]->value);
        }
        else {
            ll *head = hash[i];
            printf("[ ");
            while (head->next != NULL){
                printf("%d, ", head->value);
                head = head->next;
            }
            printf("%d ]", head->value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int choice = 0, value;
    int element;
    while (1){
        printf("\tAddend - 1\n\tDisplay - 2\n\tDelete - 3\n");
        printf(" > ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1){
            system("cls");
            printf("-->Enter item: ");
            scanf("%d", &element);
            printf("-->Enter value: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            add(element, value);
        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            system("cls");
            printf("-->Display");
            printf("\n");
            display();
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            system("cls");
            printf("-->Delete\n");
            printf("-->Enter value: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            delete_value(value);
        }
    }
}
```